# How can I get my css to work on label GWT Java

Tags: java, css, netbeans, gwt

I'm playing around with GWT using Netbeans and Java. I have several labels and buttons with css styling which are working, however, I have added another label which I cant seem to get the css to work!

```
final Label numbersLabel = new Label();

numbersLabel.setStyleName("numberLabel");

drawButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            int numberTest;
            String number;
            numberTest = testRandom.testNumbers();
            number = Integer.toString(numberTest);
            numbersLabel.setText(number);
            RootPanel.get().add(numbersLabel);

        }
    });
```

Here is the CSS

```
.numberLabel {
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center; }
```

On the button click, the label is displayed however, none of the css is implemented. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but try to add the html element with online style like String str =“<h style=‘color:white’>text here </>”; into the constructor of the Label I need to check the java api doc

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that did nothing.

Comment: pfff..... sorry. The browser was loading the file from cache and not the actual file. All good. rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go with:

```
numbersLabel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("color", "white");
```

And so on...

**But remember to always write the Style Atrribute Name in CamelCase e.g. font-family = fontFamily**